# Can I send SQlite database data in Xamarin Forms to Wear application

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, wear-os

I have a SQlite based Xamarin Forms application on my Android Phone and Wear device. Syncing between my Phone and my Wear watch is performed according to [my answer to another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692220/how-to-run-a-xamarin-forms-application-on-an-android-wear-device/47496211#47496211).

My database has the folowing tables Match and MatchStat:

```
public class Match
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatchDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan MatchTime { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string Guest { get; set; }
    public int HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int GuestScore { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public string HomeColor { get; set; }
    public string GuestColor { get; set; }

    public Match()
    { }
}

public class MatchStat
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public int ActionMin { get; set; }
    public int HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int GuestScore { get; set; }
    public string ActionItem { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }

    public MatchStat()
    { }
}
```

If I want to sync my Match and all the MatchStat data from one device to the other I am doing it by mapping the data as strings in my MainActivity:

```
    public async static void SendNewMatch(Match match, string path)
    {
        if (!client.IsConnected)
            client.Connect();
        await Task.Delay(200);
        try
        {
            var request = PutDataMapRequest.Create(path);
            var map = request.DataMap;

            if (match != null)
            {
                map.PutString("Device", device);
                map.PutString("Item", "AddMatch");
                map.PutString("Home", match.Home);
                map.PutString("Guest", match.Guest);
                map.PutString("Active", match.Active.ToString());
                map.PutString("Done", match.Done.ToString());
                map.PutString("GuestScore", match.GuestScore.ToString());
                map.PutString("HomeScore", match.HomeScore.ToString());
                map.PutString("Date", match.MatchDate.Date.ToString());
                map.PutString("Time", match.MatchTime.ToString());
                map.PutLong("UpdatedAt", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
                await WearableClass.DataApi.PutDataItem(client, request.AsPutDataRequest());
            }
            request.UnregisterFromRuntime();
        }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }

    }

    public async static void SendMatchStat(MatchStat matchstat, Match match, int matchstatsize, string path)
    {
        if (!client.IsConnected)
            client.Connect();
        await Task.Delay(200);
        try
        {
            var request = PutDataMapRequest.Create(path);
            var map = request.DataMap;
            MatchHelper mh = new MatchHelper();

            if (matchstat != null)
            {
                map.PutString("Device", device);
                map.PutString("Item", "MatchStat");
                map.PutString("Home", match.Home);
                map.PutString("Date", match.MatchDate.Date.ToString());
                map.PutString("Time", match.MatchTime.ToString());
                map.PutString("ActionItem", matchstat.ActionItem);
                map.PutString("ActionMin", matchstat.ActionMin.ToString());
                map.PutString("GuestScore", matchstat.GuestScore.ToString());
                map.PutString("HomeScore", matchstat.HomeScore.ToString());
                map.PutString("MatchStatSize", matchstatsize.ToString());
                //map.PutString("PlayerName", matchstat.PlayerName.ToString());
                map.PutLong("UpdatedAt", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
                await WearableClass.DataApi.PutDataItem(client, request.AsPutDataRequest());
            }
            request.UnregisterFromRuntime();
        }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }

    }

    public void ProcessMessage(Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.GetStringExtra("Device") != device)
        {
            switch (intent.GetStringExtra("Item"))
            {
                case "AddMatch":
                    {
                        AddMatch(intent);
                        break;
                    }
                case "MatchStat":
                    {
                        InsertMatchStat(intent);
                        break;
                    }

            }
        }
    }

    private void AddMatch(Intent intent)
    {
        MatchHelper mh = new MatchHelper();
        if (bool.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Active")))
        {
            ObservableCollection<Match> activeMatches = mh.GetActiveMatches();
            foreach (Match activeMatch in activeMatches)
            {
                mh.InactivateMatch(activeMatch);
            }
        }
        Match newmatch = new Match();
        newmatch.Home = intent.GetStringExtra("Home");
        newmatch.Guest = intent.GetStringExtra("Guest");
        newmatch.HomeColor = intent.GetStringExtra("HomeColor");
        newmatch.GuestColor = intent.GetStringExtra("GuestColor");
        newmatch.Active = bool.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Active"));
        newmatch.Done = bool.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Done"));
        newmatch.HomeScore = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("HomeScore"));
        newmatch.GuestScore = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("GuestScore"));
        newmatch.Active = bool.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Active"));
        newmatch.Done = bool.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Done"));
        newmatch.MatchDate = DateTime.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Date"));
        newmatch.MatchTime = TimeSpan.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Time"));
        mh.InsertMatch(newmatch);
    }

    private void InsertMatchStat(Intent intent)
    {
        MatchHelper mh = new MatchHelper();
        Match match = mh.GetSpecificMatch(intent.GetStringExtra("Home"), DateTime.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Date")), TimeSpan.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Time")));
        if (match != null)
        {
            MatchStat machstat = new MatchStat();
            machstat.MatchId = match.Id;
            machstat.ActionItem = intent.GetStringExtra("ActionItem");
            machstat.ActionMin = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("ActionMin"));
            machstat.GuestScore = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("GuestScore"));
            machstat.HomeScore = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("HomeScore"));
            machstat.PlayerName = intent.GetStringExtra("PlayerName");

            mh.InsertMatchStat(machstat);

        }
    }
```

In my WearService I have my OnDataChanged:

```
    public override void OnDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents)
    {
        var dataEvent = Enumerable.Range(0, dataEvents.Count)
                                  .Select(i => dataEvents.Get(i).JavaCast<IDataEvent>())
                                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == DataEvent.TypeChanged && x.DataItem.Uri.Path.Equals(_syncPath));
        if (dataEvent == null)
            return;

        //get data from wearable
        var dataMapItem = DataMapItem.FromDataItem(dataEvent.DataItem);
        var map = dataMapItem.DataMap;

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);

        intent.PutExtra("Device", map.GetString("Device"));
        intent.PutExtra("Item", map.GetString("Item"));

        switch (map.GetString("Item"))
        {
            case "AddMatch":
                {
                    intent.PutExtra("Home", map.GetString("Home"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Guest", map.GetString("Guest"));
                    intent.PutExtra("HomeColor", map.GetString("HomeColor"));
                    intent.PutExtra("GuestColor", map.GetString("GuestColor"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Active", map.GetString("Active"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Done", map.GetString("Done"));
                    intent.PutExtra("HomeScore", map.GetString("HomeScore"));
                    intent.PutExtra("GuestScore", map.GetString("GuestScore"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Date", map.GetString("Date"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Time", map.GetString("Time"));
                    LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;
                }
            case "MatchStat":
                {
                    intent.PutExtra("Home", map.GetString("Home"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Date", map.GetString("Date"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Time", map.GetString("Time"));
                    intent.PutExtra("ActionItem", map.GetString("ActionItem"));
                    intent.PutExtra("ActionMin", map.GetString("ActionMin"));
                    intent.PutExtra("GuestScore", map.GetString("GuestScore"));
                    intent.PutExtra("HomeScore", map.GetString("HomeScore"));
                    intent.PutExtra("PlayerName", map.GetString("PlayerName"));
                    LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Instead of sending the data via separate strings I want to send my Match data as database file (if necessary as .ToString). Is it possible to achieve this and how can I thereafter retrieve the data.

Second of all I have my MatchStats as a list (IEnumerable or ObservableCollection). Is it possible to send this as a list or do I have to send each MatchStat seperately. By sending the Matchstats seperately my other device will not receive them in the desired order and not all MatchStats are received.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending database data as database file I now solved this by sending the Matchstats in one file instead of sending all seperate data.

```
    public async static void SendMatchStats(ObservableCollection<MatchStat> matchstats, Match match, int matchstatsize, string path)
    {
        if (!client.IsConnected)
            client.Connect();
        await Task.Delay(80);
        try
        {
            var request = PutDataMapRequest.Create(path);
            var map = request.DataMap;
            MatchHelper mh = new MatchHelper();
            int cnt = 1;
            if (matchstatsize != 0)
            {
                map.PutString("Device", device);
                map.PutString("Item", "MatchStats");
                map.PutString("Home", match.Home);
                map.PutString("Date", match.MatchDate.Date.ToString());
                map.PutString("Time", match.MatchTime.ToString());
                map.PutString("MatchStatSize", matchstatsize.ToString());
                map.PutString("Path", path);
                foreach (MatchStat matchstat in matchstats)
                {
                    map.PutString("ActionItem" + cnt.ToString(), matchstat.ActionItem);
                    map.PutString("ActionMin" + cnt.ToString(), matchstat.ActionMin.ToString());
                    map.PutString("Color" + cnt.ToString(), matchstat.Color);
                    //map.PutString("ColorSchemeId", matchstat.ColorSchemeId.ToString());
                    map.PutString("GuestScore" + cnt.ToString(), matchstat.GuestScore.ToString());
                    map.PutString("HomeScore" + cnt.ToString(), matchstat.HomeScore.ToString());
                    if (matchstat.PlayerName == null)
                        map.PutString("PlayerName" + cnt.ToString(), "");
                    else
                        map.PutString("PlayerName" + cnt.ToString(), matchstat.PlayerName.ToString());
                    cnt++;
                }
                map.PutLong("UpdatedAt", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
                await WearableClass.DataApi.PutDataItem(client, request.AsPutDataRequest());
            }
            request.SetUrgent();
            request.UnregisterFromRuntime();
        }
        catch
        { }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }

    }
```

In my WearService I have my OnDataChanged:

```
                case "MatchStats":
                {
                    int size = int.Parse(map.GetString("MatchStatSize"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Home", map.GetString("Home"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Date", map.GetString("Date"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Time", map.GetString("Time"));
                    intent.PutExtra("MatchStatSize", map.GetString("MatchStatSize"));
                    intent.PutExtra("Path", map.GetString("Path"));
                    for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= size; cnt++)
                    {
                        intent.PutExtra("ActionItem" + cnt.ToString(), map.GetString("ActionItem" + cnt.ToString()));
                        intent.PutExtra("ActionMin" + cnt.ToString(), map.GetString("ActionMin" + cnt.ToString()));
                        intent.PutExtra("Color" + cnt.ToString(), map.GetString("Color" + cnt.ToString()));
                        intent.PutExtra("GuestScore" + cnt.ToString(), map.GetString("GuestScore" + cnt.ToString()));
                        intent.PutExtra("HomeScore" + cnt.ToString(), map.GetString("HomeScore" + cnt.ToString()));
                        intent.PutExtra("PlayerName" + cnt.ToString(), map.GetString("PlayerName" + cnt.ToString()));
                        Console.WriteLine("PutExtra " + map.GetString("ActionMin" + cnt.ToString()) + " min " + map.GetString("HomeScore" + cnt.ToString()) + "-" + map.GetString("GuestScore" + cnt.ToString()));
                        Console.WriteLine("GetStringExtra " + intent.GetStringExtra("ActionMin" + cnt.ToString()) + " min " + intent.GetStringExtra("HomeScore" + cnt.ToString()) + "-" + intent.GetStringExtra("GuestScore" + cnt.ToString()));
                    }
                    LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(intent);
                    break;
                }
```

And in MainActivity I am processing the data in a seperate void InsertMatchstats:

```
    private void InsertMatchStats(Intent intent)
    {
        MatchHelper mh = new MatchHelper();
        Match match = mh.GetSpecificMatch(intent.GetStringExtra("Home"), DateTime.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Date")), TimeSpan.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("Time")));
        int size = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("MatchStatSize"));
        if (match != null)
        {

            for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= size; cnt++)
            {
                MatchStat matchstat = new MatchStat
                {
                    MatchId = match.Id,
                    ActionItem = intent.GetStringExtra("ActionItem" + cnt.ToString()),
                    ActionMin = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("ActionMin" + cnt.ToString())),
                    Color = intent.GetStringExtra("Color" + cnt.ToString()),
                    //ColorSchemeId = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("ColorSchemeId"));
                    GuestScore = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("GuestScore" + cnt.ToString())),
                    HomeScore = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("HomeScore" + cnt.ToString())),
                    PlayerName = intent.GetStringExtra("PlayerName" + cnt.ToString()),
                    Sync = true
                };
                if (matchstat.Color == null)
                    matchstat.Color = "#FFFFFF";
                MatchStat checkMatchStat = mh.CheckMatchStat(matchstat.HomeScore, matchstat.GuestScore, matchstat.ActionItem, matchstat.MatchId);
                if (checkMatchStat == null)
                    mh.InsertMatchStat(matchstat);
                else
                {
                    checkMatchStat.ActionMin = matchstat.ActionMin;
                    checkMatchStat.Color = matchstat.Color;
                    //checkMatchStat.ColorSchemeId = matchstat.ColorSchemeId;
                    checkMatchStat.PlayerName = matchstat.PlayerName;
                    mh.UpdateMatchStat(checkMatchStat);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("PutExtra " + intent.GetStringExtra("ActionMin" + cnt.ToString()) + " min " + intent.GetStringExtra("HomeScore" + cnt.ToString()) + "-" + intent.GetStringExtra("GuestScore" + cnt.ToString()));
            }
            SendBack(intent.GetStringExtra("Path"));

        }
    }
```

Using this method the syncing is much faster and more precise. No data is lost and all data is received and processed in the right order.